# startMonitoringForRegion:desiredAccuracy: vs startMonitoringForRegion:

Tags: iphone, core-location, ios5

IOS4 has a startMonitoringForRegion:desiredAccuracy: method.

IOS5 added startMonitoringForRegion: (without accuracy).

All the documentation says is that "You must call this [new] method or the startMonitoringForRegion:desiredAccuracy: method" etc. No details are given.

Does anybody know what's the difference between the two? Should I call the IOS5 method if it's supported?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It really depends on what you need. Notice what the desired accuracy parameter means is:

> You specify the desired cushion distance for a region when you register it using the startMonitoringForRegion:desiredAccuracy: method. This cushion value prevents the system from generating numerous entered and exited events in quick succession while the user is traveling close the edge of the boundary."

In my understanding and from my testing, the new method that doesn't use this parameter uses some internal logic to know when to fire the event. (Seems like it depends on whether the wifi is on or off and the current location accuracy in general...)

Answer (score 0):

It is basically an updated method that allows you to add calls for accuracy. The older method is supported for iOS 4 devices without having them fail. I haven't tried the calls without the accuracy hook, but my guess it they should work similar, but the accuracy lets the system know how often to update for even better battery life.

Comment: I'm afraid it's the other way around... The call without accuracy is what's been added in IOS5.

Answer (score 0):

The iOS5 method, startMonitoringForRegion: (without accuracy), uses the desiredAccuracy property of your CLLocationManager object to determine the level of accuracy to use.  It's essentially equivalent to:

```
[myLocationManager startMonitoringForRegion:myRegion desiredAccuracy:myLocationManager.desiredAccuracy];
```

So use the iOS5 method if you're already setting your desired accuracy elsewhere, but use the iOS4 method if you're not setting it elsewhere, or you want to override the existing desiredAccuracy.